# Event using generic EventHandler<> not visible in Designer

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, events, designer

I've just noticed that if I add an event using a generic eventhandler to my UserControl, the event is not visible in the designer when I add the user control to a form.

```
public event EventHandler<TEventArgs<int>> EventNotVisibleInDesigner;
public event EventHandler EventVisibleInDesigner;
```

Not particularly worrisome, but is this by-design/normal, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It might be helpful to specify what presentation framework you are using (Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET, etc.)

Comment: @luksan, you're right, tags updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Windows Forms designer has limited support for generic types.  It will work okay when you avoid the generic type argument for `EventHandler<T>`:

```
    public class TEventArgs<T> : EventArgs { }
    public class MyEventArgs : TEventArgs<int> { }
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> EventNowAlsoVisibleInDesigner;
```

Comment: Very crafty! Thanks for that.