# Workaround for generic event handler in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, visual-studio-2013, event-handling

Quite some time ago, I noticed that the Windows Forms editor of Visual Studio does not support events which contain generic type parameters. For example, an event like

```
public event EventHandler<ListEventArgs<int>> MyStrangeEvent { add { ... } remove { ... } }
```

where

```
public class ListEventArgs<T> : EventArgs { List<T> args; }
```

does not even show up in the event list in the property manager of Visual Studio. Now, this is a somewhat artificial example that could easily be modified to work in Visual Studio by rewriting the classes and their events. However, I am currently working on a project where I cannot change some classes for compatibility reasons. The only thing I can do is to change the events of my user control. The events of this control currently look like this:

```
public event EventHandler<Plane<GDISurface>.DrawingErrorEventArgs> DrawingError { add { _Plane.DrawingError += value; } remove { _Plane.DrawingError -= value; } }
```

Note that the underlying Plane class (represented by the _Plane instance which is a protected field) cannot be changed. Its DrawingError event and its EventArgs type are declared in the Plane class like this:

```
public class Plane<T> where T : ISurface
{
    ...
    public event EventHandler<DrawingErrorEventArgs> DrawingError = null;
    ...
    public class DrawingErrorEventArgs : EventArgs { ... /* Uses T */ ... }
}
```

Of course, the Windows Forms editor of Visual Studio does not show any of the events of my user control. I have been looking for a number of workarounds to get them shown again, but have not been able to find a workaround that actually works. Here are some things that I tried:

1. Created a MyPlane class which inherits from Plane and used that instead: `public event EventHandler<MyPlane.DrawingErrorEventArgs> DrawingError ...`. For reasons unknown to me, the events still don't show up in the editor. Perhaps this is due to the parameters of the event, some of which still are generic. Find a minimal working example below.
2. Created a helper class which defines implicit conversion operators between `EventHandler<Plane<GDISurface>.DrawingErrorEventArgs>` and `EventHandler<GDIPlane.DrawingErrorEventArgs>` where GDIPlane is just a dummy class which inherits from `Plane<GDISurface>`. This does work to some extent, but duplicates event calls since the conversion creates new event handlers which are passed down to _Plane which cannot be removed/unregistered properly.
3. Tried to inherit from `EventHandler<Plane<GDISurface>.DrawingErrorEventArgs>`, which obviously does not work since `EventHandler<T>` is sealed.

Are there any other ways to make my events visible again in the Windows Forms editor?

Best regards
Andreas

EDIT: Minimal working example for 1:

```
public interface ISurface { }

public class GDISurface : ISurface { }

public class Plane<T> where T : ISurface
{
    public event EventHandler<DrawingErrorEventArgs> DrawingError = null;
    public class DrawingErrorEventArgs : EventArgs { T stuff; }
}

public class TestControl : UserControl
{
    public class GDIPlane : Plane<GDISurface>  { }
    GDIPlane _Plane = null;
    public event EventHandler<GDIPlane.DrawingErrorEventArgs> DrawingError { add { _Plane.DrawingError += value; } remove { _Plane.DrawingError -= value; } }
}
```

DrawingError does not show up in the list of events in the property manager when clicking on a TestControl instance.

EDIT2: This is the original problem (without any workarounds) where the DrawingError event does of TestControl does not show up either:

```
public interface ISurface { }

public class GDISurface : ISurface { }

public class Plane<T> where T : ISurface
{
    public event EventHandler<DrawingErrorEventArgs> DrawingError = null;
    public class DrawingErrorEventArgs : EventArgs { T stuff; }
}

public class TestControl : UserControl
{
    Plane<GDISurface> _Plane = null;
    public event EventHandler<Plane<GDISurface>.DrawingErrorEventArgs> DrawingError { add { _Plane.DrawingError += value; } remove { _Plane.DrawingError -= value; } }
}
```

Comment: Best and very easy workaround is to subscribe the event in constructor programmatically than finding way to make the designer to work. Just keep away from designer if that doesn't work.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: The point of having a user control in the first place is to make the functionality accessible in an easier way during design time. A user control which largely relies on the use of its events is pretty much pointless when these events cannot be accessed through the designer.

Comment: That's not what the point of using `UserControl`. UserControl is used to group the related funtionalities together and make them collaborate. You're going out of your way to make the designer work, but subscribing the event in constructor is often easier thing to do.

Comment: My user control groups a lot of related functionality together, but, on top of that, it has to make some of the events of its underlying components available. Due to the total amount of events, a workaround to use them in the designer would make their use enormously easier than to register to each and every one of them separately in the constructor.

Comment: #1 works fine for me. No one can tell you why it doesn't work for you without a good code example. #2 isn't clear to me; I'm able to write a non-generic subclass to use for an event, and delegate type variance solves the rest (i.e. I just change the handler signature back to the generic type and it works fine)...I don't know why you need implicit conversion or have duplicate event calls/new event handlers. In any case, I tend to agree with Sriram. You're putting in a lot of effort just so you can use the clickable designer; heck, typing would probably be faster most of the time anyway.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I added a minimal working example for #1. Would you care to elaborate on #2, possibly with an example? Maybe my thinking is just too complicated.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. A good code example is both minimal and _complete_. Without completeness, the only truly "minimal" example is the one without _any_ code (which is obviously not useful). It's also not clear what you example is intended to illustrate: is the interface really required for the example? is the _hiding_ of the base class event an important part of what you mean to show? did you expect the designer to show both events? Obviously, the base class event won't be shown; it's _hidden_!

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I want the DrawingError event of the TestControl control shown in the designer. The interface is necessary since it imposes a constraint on the generic type parameter. I can provide a screenshot of the designer which is lacking the DrawingError event if necessary.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I added another example for the original problem (without any workarounds); as I explained above, it does not work since the designer does not support these kinds generic types as events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event using generic EventHandler<> not visible in Designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727021/event-using-generic-eventhandler-not-visible-in-designer)

Comment: retracted my close vote, this differs from existing/related questions in that the OP is specifically looking for a viable workaround for his case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is behavior specific to Visual Studio, and the cause is rooted in the fact that EventHandler<> does not specify covariance on its 'TEventArgs' (it would impose seemingly silly restrictions) and the tools do not perform enough introspection of your code to suss out an appropriate type (even though you've left a trail of type data in constructing the control.) Thus, it seems as though VS does not support generic event properties. You may consider filing a feature request on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio), I wouldn't suggest filing it as a bug as they may label it "by design" and close it.

As a general rule, if you *need* generic type parameters on your events and you *need* design time support for them (which are different implementation concerns), you're looking at wrapping them in a presentation-specific facade (e.g. "extra layer of code to facilitate design-time needs".)

Personally, I would reduce the generic typing you have in play now, it seems a bit excessive and if you don't understand covariance/contravariance in generic types it might put you in a tight spot at some point, such as now.

**However, to work around your problem:**

Consider using a custom event args class which could transport data in a non-generic property, and also use a non-generic `EventHandler` event/property. Understanding the 'type' of the event is then shifted away from generic type parameters and made the responsibility of your non-generic event args instead. If the 'class' of the event args is insufficient, you can add a property to convey the event type (or data type) so that receiving code can properly interpret it (assuming, of course, that it does not already know by some other means.):

```
public class DataEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    //public string EventTypeOrPurpose { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

This is most often only used to ferry data through an event chain, and it is usually implemented as follows:

```
public class DataEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, this also has a covariance problem, to resolve it you would actually want something more like this:

```
public interface IDataArgs<out T>
{
    T Data { get; }
}

public class DataEventArgs<T> : EventArgs, IDataArgs<T>
{
    public DataEventArgs<T>(T data) 
    {
        _data = data;
    }
    private T _data;
    public T Data { get { return _data; } }
}
```

Even so, **these generic versions still don't work around Visual Studio's limitations**, this is merely more proper alternative forms of what you already have shown us.

**UPDATE: As requested, here is what a "purpose built facade" might look like** in the most basic sense. Note that the usercontrol functions as a facade layer in this case as the eventhandler it exposes delegates to the underlying object model. There is no direct access to underlying object model from the user control (from consumer/designer perspective.)

Please note the reference tracking for event handlers is not necessary unless you dispose of these user controls throughout the lifetime of the app (it is only done to ensure proper delegate removal based on the delegate provided, which is wrapped in a closure/delegate, as you see below.)

Also worth noting I did not test-run this code beyond verifying that the designer shows `DrawingError` in the property grid when dropped onto a form.

```
namespace SampleCase3
{
    public interface ISurface { }

    public class GDISurface : ISurface { }

    public class Plane<T> where T : ISurface
    {
        public event EventHandler<DrawingErrorEventArgs> DrawingError;
        public class DrawingErrorEventArgs : EventArgs { T stuff; }
    }

    public class TestControl : UserControl
    {
        private Plane<GDISurface> _Plane = new Plane<GDISurface>(); // requires initialization for my own testing

        public TestControl()
        {
        }

        // i am adding this map *only* so that the removal of an event handler can be done properly
        private Dictionary<EventHandler, EventHandler<Plane<GDISurface>.DrawingErrorEventArgs>> _cleanupMap = new Dictionary<EventHandler, EventHandler<Plane<GDISurface>.DrawingErrorEventArgs>>();

        public event EventHandler DrawingError
        {
            add
            {
                var nonGenericHandler = value;
                var genericHandler = (EventHandler<Plane<GDISurface>.DrawingErrorEventArgs>)delegate(object sender, Plane<GDISurface>.DrawingErrorEventArgs e)
                {
                    nonGenericHandler(sender, e);
                };
                _Plane.DrawingError += genericHandler;
                _cleanupMap[nonGenericHandler] = genericHandler;
            }
            remove
            {
                var nonGenericHandler = value;
                var genericHandler = default(EventHandler<Plane<GDISurface>.DrawingErrorEventArgs>);
                if (_cleanupMap.TryGetValue(nonGenericHandler, out genericHandler))
                {
                    _Plane.DrawingError -= genericHandler;
                    _cleanupMap.Remove(nonGenericHandler);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To complement the above, here is what a non-generic event handler would now look like:

```
private void testControl1_DrawingError(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var genericDrawingErrorEventArgs = e as Plane<GDISurface>.DrawingErrorEventArgs;
    if (genericDrawingErrorEventArgs != null)
    {
        // TODO:
    }
}
```

Note that the consumer here has to have knowledge of the type for `e` to perform conversion. The use of the `as` operator will bypass ancestry checks under the assumption that the conversion should succeed.

Something like this is as close as you're going to get. Yes it is ugly by most of our standards, but if you absolutely 'need' design-time support on top of these components and you cannot change `Plane<T>` (which would be more appropriate) then this, or something close to this, is the only viable workaround.

HTH

Comment: If I use non-generic EventArgs, like `public class GDIDrawingErrorEventArgs : Plane<GDISurface>.DrawingErrorEventArgs { }` and `public event EventHandler<GDIDrawingErrorEventArgs> DrawingError { add { _Plane.DrawingError += value; } remove { _Plane.DrawingError -= value; } }` the compiler complains that the event types are not compatible. This is what I already tried in item #2 in my original post. Since I **cannot** change the event type of the Plane class (as explained above), this does not work for me.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, what I am saying is (1) you need to use non-generic event types to gain Designer support in visual studio, this may require a purpose-built facade to wrap the generic code since you cannot change `Plane<T>`. In your example you are still trying to use `EventHandler<>`, this necessarily must not be part of your solution, that is precisely the problem, you need to use the non-generic `EventHandler` and re-read the answer around "Understanding the 'type".

Comment: (2) You also appear to be using `Plane<T>` in the inheritance chain, which will only create variance problems unrelated to this question, you may find MSDN's reference on Variance in C# of value https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx - this is why I suspect you will need a full facade to support these events in a designer, and it will necessarily need to hide the generic parameters introduced by Plane<T>

Comment: Obviously, I did not fully understand your previous answer. Part of my confusion was due to the fact that the linked "possible duplicate" shows a workaround which does pretty much what I tried above, i.e., use `EventHandler<SomeTypeWhichDoesNotUseGenerics>`, which you explained caused problems. To avoid any further confusion, would you be so kind as to provide a minimal example for what you refered to as "purpose-build facade"? I am imagining some sort of helper class which wraps the behavior of my DawingErrorEventArgs, but I am not sure how to use that with _Plane.DrawingError. Thank you.

Comment: To add to that: I read about variance (thank you for the link; it is indeed of value for me) and thought that a compatible delegate should be able to do the trick: `public delegate void GDIDrawingErrorEventArgs(object sender, Plane<GDISurface>.DrawingErrorEventArgs e);`. Unfortunately, this does not work as `public event GDIDrawingErrorEventArgs DrawingError { add { _Plane.DrawingError += value; } remove { _Plane.DrawingError -= value; } }` complains about incompatible delegates, but I can at least add it to the list of things I tried :).

Comment: You may want to branch off a separate question to cover/explore variance problems separate from workarounds for VS design-time limitations, as creating and then solving variance problems will not lend to any different workarounds here.

Comment: Sorry, this was just an idea I got after reading your link on variance. To restate my question from before: Would you be so kind as to provide an example for what you call a ""purpose-build facade"? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Updated the question before commenting. :) In the example provided my "purpose built facade" is merely an EventHandler which is delegated to by an internally allocated EventHandler<TEventArgs>. It's "purpose built" because the only reason you would write this code is to work around the VS limitation. It's a "facade" because Visual Studio is entirely shielded from the fact that, internally, EventHandler<> is being used. You could adapt some of the code into a re-usable "EventHandlerProxy" class, it's debatable the best way to go about it. I'll give it some more thought and update later.