# Is it possible to have a generic delegate?

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

I have a base generic usercontrol defined as:

```
public partial class BaseUserControl<T> : UserControl where T : class
{
    public event ItemsSelectedEventHandler ItemsSelected;
}
```

And a delegate:

```
public class ItemsSelectedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; private set; }

    internal ItemsSelectedEventArgs(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this.Items = items;
    }
}
public delegate void ItemsSelectedEventHandler(object sender, ItemsSelectedEventArgs<T> e);
```

A method of this usercontrol is to load multiple records at once and return them as `IEnumerable<T>`. Inheriting controls will then be of a concrete type, and they will in turn raise the event to the subscriber (ie. form).

However, the above doesn't compile and I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is it possible to achieve want I need in some other way?

Comment: you're just missing `<T>` in the method name :) `public delegate void ItemsSelectedEventHandler<T>(object sender, ItemsSelectedEventArgs<T> e);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can. The error is in your last line - you haven't declared the "T" as generic. Instead of:

```
public delegate void ItemsSelectedEventHandler(object sender, ItemsSelectedEventArgs<T> e);
```

It should be:

```
public delegate void ItemsSelectedEventHandler<T>(object sender, ItemsSelectedEventArgs<T> e);
```

Comment: When subscribing to the event using the form designer, it adds the event handler method with just `sender` as parameter. Why doesn't it add `ItemsSelectedEventArgs<ConcreteTypeClass> e` too?

Comment: WinForms is a bit limited when it comes to designer support for generics... maybe take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28527350/79444) for a possible solution...

Answer (score 2):

```
public delegate void ItemsSelectedEventHandler<T>(object sender, ItemsSelectedEventArgs<T> e);
```

Also you can use predefined generic `EventHandler<T>` like this:

```
public event EventHandler<ItemsSelectedEventArgs<SomeType>> SomeEvent;
```

Comment: You should explain whats different and how it fixes the problem rather than posting code only answers.